# Laravel Model Inheritance: how can I instantiate model of correct type from parent

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent

I want to avoid inheritance as much as possible, but I have a case in existing code that I need to work with.

Consider a model `CartItem` which is being inherited by different implementation models, such as `CartItemTypeX` and `CartItemTypeY`

The three models share the same database table cart_items, and have the exact same structure.  One of the columns is named `payload` and its content can be different for each of the types, which is why we have the different models.

The table also has a column `type` which is being saved automatically by the following simple logic:

```
static::creating(function (Model $model) {
    $model->type = $model->getMorphClass();
});
```

So far so good.  Each CartItem is properly being saved into the database with its proper type.

Now, we have some routes that accept a `CartItem` as a parameter.
For instance, let's consider the following:

```
class SomeController {
    public function update(CartItemRequest $request, CartItem $cartItem) {
        // Our logic goes here...
        // We would like $cartItem to automatically be of the implementation type (CartItemTypeX for instance)
    }
}
```

I have some additional hurdles to take when tackling this issue.  For instance, our optimistic locking mechanism saves the version if of the model in a related model.  It does that using a morph relationship, so it has the morph class `CartItemTypeX` and not `CartItem` because we never save a `CartItem` as such.

This is what I have been looking into.

**Overriding the `newFromBuilder` method on `CartItem`**

I tried overriding this method on the class, like this:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    $classname = Relation::getMorphedModel($attributes->type);
    $instance = new $classname();
    $instance->exists = true;
    $instance->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);
    $instance->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

    $instance->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);
    return $instance;
}
```

This seems to be working fine when I'm retrieving the models through the builder (for instance `CartItem::whereIsNull('order_id')->get()` will return `CartItemTypeX` models (I just remember I haven't tried testing with different cart types, but I suspect that this would work...)

however, when the `CartItem` is being injected from the route into my controller, it's still a model of type `CartItem` and not `CartItemTypeX`  So that didn't do the trick to me.

**Just adding a method to get the implementation**

So I forgot about delegating this responsibility to Eloquent (which had my preference, as I want to keep my controller and business code as clean and simple as possible)

I then tried applying the same logic as above in a new method adding to the `CartItem` class:

```
class CartItem {
    public function getImplementation() {
        $classname = Relation::getMorphedModel($this->type);
        $instance = new $classname();
        $instance->exists = $this->exists;
        $instance->setRawAttributes((array) $this->attributes, true);
        $instance->setConnection($this->connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

and in my controller, I can then easily do this:

```
class MyController {
    public function view(Request $request, CartItem $cartItem) {
        $cartItem = $cartItem->getImplementation();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

That works as well, but my versioning trait I discussed above is failing on me.  On retrieving the Model, this trait fetches the related through the morph relation.  As it was of type `CartItem` when being retrieved from the databases, it uses the morph type for `CartItem` and not `CartItemTypeX` to retrieve it from the database.

So by just in code instantiating the correct implementation class and setting attributes rawly (is that a word?), we do not have the correct value for `version` which raises conflicts when the model is being saved.

**So back to the first solution?**

The first solution I inherited in the code, is something like this:

```
class CartItem {
    public function getImplementation() {
        $classname = Relation::getMorphedModel($this->type);
        return $classname::find($this->id);
    }
}
```

and yes, this works.  I get in a `CartItem` and by doing `$cartItem->getImplementation()`, Eloquent is retrieving the `CartItemTypeX` from the database.  The trait for versioning (optimistic locking) also works as it is supposed to do, as we are just fetching it freshly from the database...

Oh - and there's that issue again... a fresh retrieve.  This implementation is killing performance obviously, as to retrieve a CartItemTypeX, we will now always have two retrieves: One for `CartItem` because of route parameter injection into the controller method, and a second time when we fetch the implementation.

Surely there must be a better way.  Any thoughts or insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: I tried your solutions in a fresh laravel 5.8 project and the route model binging seems to work for me as well as querying directly on the model if you override `newFromBuilder` method. Which laravel version are you using? The route model binding shuld not differ from queries on the model because under the hood they both end up calling the `newFromBuilder` method

Comment: Hmm - not sure how that went then.  I decided to refactor the whole thing for now.  I'm sure I got the parent class which made me go crazy to be honest.

Comment: The only difference I had from your code was the `$model->setTable($this->getTable());` function after the `$instance->exists = true;`, but commenting that out made no difference at all. By the way you were on the right track I think. If you want to further investigate that solution and want help I might as well open a chat discussion. Let me know!

Comment: I'm going to save this for later reference - might be interested in chatting with you.  Currently just wasted too much time and on a time constraint here (as always) - when re-reading this question I even wonder where I got the time to document it like this :D   I didn't need to `->setTable` as I had the table set on the `CartItem` class where the others inherited from.  Just refactoring, I was able to get rid of all of the Type classes (yay!).  I might want to look into creating a PR for such inheritance support in the laravel core though.  I can imagine so many use cases here!